# How can I call the method of the great grandfather in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to call a method from the great grandfather to the Athlete class,

How can I do that?

I tried using super.printSentence but that did not work,

Is this the correct way to invoke the method, super.printPositon() in the Athlete class?

Any suggestion on how to invoke this printSentence method?

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  printName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class TeamMate extends Person {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  printSentence() {
    console.log(super.printName(), "is an excellent teammate!" );
  }

}


class SoccerPlayer extends TeamMate {
  constructor(name, teamMateName, position) {
    super(name, teamMateName);
     this.teamMateName = teamMateName;
    this.position = position;
  }

  printPositon() {
    console.log("Positon: ", position);
  }
}


class Athlete extends SoccerPlayer{
  constructor(name, teamMateName, position, sport) {
    super(name, teamMateName, position);
    this.sport = sport;
  }

  printSport() {
    console.log("Favorite sport: ", this.sport);
  }

  //If Athlete class extends from SoccerPlayer and SoccerPlayer extends from 
    // the TeamMate class, how can I invoke the printSentence method 
    // from the TeamMate class in this current Athlete class?

  printGreatGrandFatherMethod() {
    return this.printSentence()
  }
}

const soccerPlayer = new Athlete('PLAYER1', 'Frederick', 'Defender', 'Soccer');
console.log(soccerPlayer.printGreatGrandFatherMethod());
```

Why am I getting undefined for the name field?

Comment: `console.log(super.printName() "is an excellent teammate!" );` that should be a nice error message in your console.

Comment: `this.printSentence()`?

Comment: Unless you've overridden the method in the current class and need to call the inherited method, you don't need to specify the class explicitly.

Comment: You've misspelled *Position* as `Positon` in a few places.  Also `printSentence()` doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to `this.printSentence()`

In inheritance (prototype or not) the `this` has access to all the methods.

Unless you are using private method like this:

```
class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  #privateMethod() {
    return 'hello world';
  }
}
```

If you think about it, if a `Person` has a `name` any class that inherited from `Person` will also have a member `name`. This is also true to any instance of a class that inherits from `Person`. for example:

```
const soccerPlayer = new SoccerPlayer('PLAYER1', 'MATE NAME', '1');
console.log(soccerPlayer.name); // Prints `PLAYER1`
```

Answer (score 1):

`printSentence()` doesn't return a value, so `return this.printSentence()` will return `undefined`.  And since that's what `printGreatGrandFatherMethod` returns, therefore `console.log(soccerPlayer.printGreatGrandFatherMethod());` will log `undefined`.

Same goes for `printName()` which doesn't return a value either and therefore `console.log(super.printName())` will log `undefined`

Comment: How can I get a value in this case?

Comment: You can't concatenate the log of one function with the log of another function.  But you could just return strings from all those functions (instead of calling console.log) and then have the _caller_ of those functions do the logging.  i.e.:  `printName` becomes `getName` which returns `this.name` and you `console.log(soccerPlayer.getName())`   `printSentence` becomes `getSentence` and returns `this.getName() + " is an excellent teammate!"` and you call `console.log(soccerPlayer.getSentence())`